# MongoDB - How to find distinct values based on partial string

Tags: mongodb

I'm not sure if this is even possible, but I'd like to get distinct domain names from urls in a Mongo distinct method. Here is some sample data:

```
     {
      stuff : "someValue",
      moreStuff : "someOtherValue",
      url : "http://mydomain.prep.com/post/290837872/myContent"
     }
     {
      stuff : "someValue",
      moreStuff : "someOtherValue",
      url : "http://mydomain.prep.com/s/44432/somethingElse"
     }
     {
      stuff : "someValue",
      moreStuff : "someOtherValue",
      url : "https://newdomain.com/ref/2"
     }
     {
      stuff : "someValue",
      moreStuff : "someOtherValue",
      url : "http://olddomain.reference.org/ref/5"
     }
     {
      stuff : "someValue",
      moreStuff : "someOtherValue",
      url : "https://newdomain.com/ref/2342"
     }
     {
      stuff : "someValue",
      moreStuff : "someOtherValue",
      url : "http://olddomain.reference.org/ref/1234"
     }
```

So based on the sample data, I'd like to get to have a distinct query that simply returns the distinct domains within the urls:

```
    {
     "0" : "http://mydomain.prep.com",
     "1" : "https://newdomain.com",
     "2" : "http://olddomain.reference.org"
    }
```

Could someone please show me how to do this query? I'm pretty new with Mongo queries and have not found a solution online. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of MongoDB 2.6.3, the string processing capabilities to do something like this aren't available. You could compute distinct domain names via map/reduce, where you'd have to write your own logic for determining a domain name from the url, but I think the easier thing is to compute the domain name on the client side and insert it in the document:

```
{
  stuff : "someValue",
  moreStuff : "someOtherValue",
  url : "http://mydomain.prep.com/post/290837872/myContent"
  domain : "mydomain.prep.com"
 }
```

Then you can use a simple distinct query

```
db.urls.distinct("domain")
```

Comment: Thanks. I was afraid this would be the answer. As you suggested, I will probably write something client-side to read through the documents, parse out the domain name and insert it.

Answer (score 5):

For Mongo 3.x you can use `$split` and `$arrayElemAt`:

```
db.test.aggregate([
  { $project : { 
      domain: {$arrayElemAt: [ { $split: ["$url", "/"] }, 2 ] }
  }},
  { $group : { 
      _id: "$domain" , count : { "$sum" : 1 } 
  }},
  { $sort:{
      _id:1
  }}
]);
```

And the result will be:

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : "mydomain.prep.com",
    "count" : 2.0
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : "newdomain.com",
    "count" : 2.0
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : "olddomain.reference.org",
    "count" : 2.0
}
```